# UIPickerView that scrolls horizontally on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm taking a look at this widget, and it appears to be a UIPickerView, however I haven't seen anything provided by the iPhone SDK API that allows for horizontal scrolling only. Mostly it's all done vertically. Also there appears to be a custom graphic around this picker, so it might not be that either.

I'm curious if anyone is able to determine if this is indeed a UIPickerView or perhaps a hacked up UIScrollView? The widget is handy -- and I like its use. I found it in some random groceries app in the app store.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Thanks all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is totally custom. You could indeed do something of the sort overlaying an UIImageView and an UIScrollView. I'd guess it's a 100% custom. As with all programming, there are many ways to do any single thing.

Answer (score 8):

I'd definitely use iCarousel library:

https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

The library is really well documented, the code is clean and maintained.

Answer (score 5):

As I recently posted in response to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594685/how-could-i-make-a-horizontal-picker) question, a class for an iOS horizontal picker control (STHorizontalPicker) has just been posted on [GitHub](https://github.com/stackthread/STHorizontalPicker). It's nowhere near as sophisticated as UIPickerView, but it provides the basic functionality for picking numeric values and the underlying foundation is probably a good starting point for adding more sophisticated functionality (it's a UIScrollView containing a UIView with multiple CATextLayers for the markers).

It was designed to be used in UITableCellViews and currently looks like this:
[image: STHorizontalPicker]

Answer (score 1):

That definitely looks like a custom component. I'd suggest getting the .app file off your iPhone, opening up the bundle, and looking to see if there's a xib file for that interface. You may get lucky and find the component sitting in there. My guess is that it's a subclass of `UIScrollView`, but of course there's no way I could be sure of that without personally knowing the developer or the codebase.

Answer (score 0):

You will recognize pickers by their giant screen-gobbling footprint :-) This is most likely a horizontal UIScrollView with a series of fixed-width labels (or images). The tricky bit is to have the bezel on top with a transparent center pass touches back to the underlying scroll view. Or you can take the easy way out and overlay four image strips (for each edge) and leave the middle open so touch events go directly to the scroller.

It's a custom control, but it's really not that hard to build.