# How could I make a horizontal picker?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, picker

I want to make a horizontal picker for my app, but I'm kinda new at all this. Could someone provide an easy to follow guide on how I'd make this?

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to fake your own using `UIScrollView` with pagination enabled. It's actually fairly easy, overlaying a scroll view with your own views for custom graphics.

Answer (score 2):

An open-source horizontal picker component for iOS has just been released on [GitHub](https://github.com/stackthread/STHorizontalPicker).

It can be added to a UITableViewCell as follows (in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`):

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
STHorizontalPicker *horizontalPickerView = [[STHorizontalPicker alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
horizontalPickerView.name = @"myPicker";
[horizontalPickerView setMinimumValue:0.0];
[horizontalPickerView setMaximumValue:100.0];
[horizontalPickerView setSteps:100];
[horizontalPickerView setDelegate:self];
[horizontalPickerView setValue:50.0];
```

It doesn't have all of the features of a UIPickerView by any means, but it illustrates one possible way to implement a control (a UIScrollView containing a UIView with multiple CATextLayers for the markers) and has a couple of nice features like snapping to markers.